Unexpected disk state: failed to read transaction log
Has anyone encountered the situation described in this DataStax article?
Any ideas on root cause i.e. under what situations does Cassandra not write ABORT or COMMIT as the last entry in the transaction logs?
Seeing this issue cluster wide with multiple "corrupt" transaction logs and empty SSTABLEs (12,000+ on some instances) which seem to be associated with this reaper error message:
ERROR   [Reference-Reaper]  12/04/2024  15:06:59,160    Ref.java:237    -   LEAK    DETECTED:   a   reference   (class  org.apache.cassandra.io.util.SafeMemory$MemoryTidy@48825611:Memory@[559a44afa520..559a44afa840)) to class org.apache.cassandra.io.util.SafeMemory$MemoryTidy@48825611:Memory@[559a44afa520..559a44afa840) was not released before the reference was garbage collected


Transaction logs can have missing entries for various reasons but they are mostly just like any other file so are vulnerable to things like power outages, hardware failures or disk full.
For example, if the server crashes while a transaction log is being written to then anything not saved prior to the server crash will be missing from the log. The same thing can happen if someone doesn't shut Cassandra down gracefully (e.g. kill -9) so it can be expected that some file(s) will be incomplete.
For what it's worth, it's not necessarily related to the error reported for the Reference-Reaper thread. That log entry in fact shouldn't be logged at ERROR level because the reaper successfully detected the memory leak and freed it up so should be logged at DEBUG or INFO level at most. Cheers!

Thanks Erick for your feedback. The cluster was UN during this time. Any other thoughts? TIA.

That doesn't mean anything.  You'll need to review the OS, C* and transaction logs for clues. Cheers!
